# CSAT Delighted Survey app is not stamping the CaseId

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have a flow on managed custom object Delighted_Response__c that has a lookup relationship with Case object. And when the case is closed it should send the Delighted Response survey to the customer (this part works fine). But when the Delighted Response is received (created) it should show the CaseId on Delighted_Response record page but it doesn't. Also the managed Delighted object has a master detail relationship with the Contact and when I get the Delighted Response back from customer it only shows the customer Name and not case.

Below is the screenshot of my flow created on Delighted_Response__c custom object when it's created in SF. Actually I have two flows one on Case object that is sending outbound message to the customer to rate the service after the case is closed. Once the customer replies back, it creates a new related record under the Contact object in Delighted Response list (and it's automated by managed package by default).

Also I've noticed that I when I am getting the new Delighted response it starts updating all cases under this certain contact and overwrites the previously created Delighted responses. And what I need is to link each Delighted response to its related case. On the Delighted record page I see only Contact Name and empty Case field.

[image: Flow on Delighted Response object]

[image: Start]

[image: isReceived = True on Delighted object]

[image: Decision if the record meets the criteria]

[image: Assignment to related case]

[image: Stamping Case Id on Delighted object]

[image: Update Case with the related Delighted id]

[image: Delighted record page with empty related Case]

[image: Case Record list with the same Delighted response]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a complete example of your implementation along with details of the negative behavior. See [ask] and [help/on-topic] for details.

Comment: If this issue is specific to behavior of an AppExchange package, you need to contact the vendor.

Comment: I will edit my post with screenshots and explanations. I've already reached out the vendor several times but unfortunately they are not helpful because as they said they "don't have great visibility into how customers are handling these types of workflows"

Comment: Just wanted to update that the issue was resolved by writing an Apex code that extracts text from Long Text Area.